# Trying to understand base condition in a search recursive in python

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to learn searching in recursive method.  The biggest hurdle for me is always the base condition to exit the loop.  Can someone really help me see this? I understand the concept of recursion and stack and all.

Say I have a function trying to find the nearest age to a given age in an array. I want to find the index in that array (which has nearest age to the given age).  So for example in:

```
arr=[23,78,51,29, 36,90, 12, 30, 79]
age=50
```

the nearest age is: 51 with index 2

If it was the age itself it would be easy just sort the array then iterate through the new sorted array and find the nearest.   BUT I need the index on original array

I like to use recursive method so I understand it.

```
def searchRecAge(arr, low, high):
    if ???:
        return
    mid=(high+low)//2
    searchRecAge(arr, low, mid-1)
    searchRecAge(arr, mid+1, high)
    
def searchNearestAgeToGivenAge(arr, age):
    arr=[23,78,51,29, 36,90, 12, 30, 79]
    age=50
    age = searchRecAge(0, len(arr)-1)
    return age
```

So this is what I have so far and not sure how to complete it.  I think I will keep finding the mid of each array and check the age is closest to mid .??

Comment: You're trying to use binary search on an unsorted array which is not correct. I recommend you to iterate through the array if you want the index of an element. Keep two variables and keep updating as you iterate through the loop.

Comment: binary searching follows the rules of binary search tree. So the array must be sorted!

Comment: Thank you didnt know,

Comment: Can someone tell me how to find the base condition to exit recursive methods.

Comment: The base condition in binary search is usually going to be something like `low == high`, or `high - low` equal to some small constant (e.g. 3 or lower). But as it was mentioned, the problem is not well-specified when the array doesn't start sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to make sure the array is **sorted**, then you need to put the value you wish to find in the array as the **recursion function parameter**. Then there are several conditions that makes the algorithm stops as described in the code below:

```py
def searchRecAge(array, value, start, end):
    if start > end: # This means the value does not exist in the array
        return -1

    mid = (start + end) // 2
    if value == array[mid]: # This handles when the value is at the middle of the array
        return mid

    # This handles when value is lower than the value at the middle of the array
    if value < array[mid]: 
        return searchRecAge(array, value, start, mid-1)

    # This handles when value is higher than the value at the middle of the array
    else:
        return searchRecAge(array, value, mid+1, end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution for solving this problem using (tail) recursion:

```py
def nearest_age(arr, age, closest):
    if not arr:
        # Base case: return the `closest` when `arr` is empty
        return closest
    elif abs(age - arr[0]) < abs(age - closest):
        # Replace `closest` with `arr[0]` if difference is small
        return nearest_age(arr[1:], age, arr[0])
    else:
        # Otherwise recur over the rest of the array
        return nearest_age(arr[1:], age, closest)


arr = [23, 78, 51, 29, 36, 90, 12, 30, 79]
age = 50
print(nearest_age(arr, age, 10000))
```

Python isn't the best language when it comes to handling recursion, so I'll show how this works with a Racket/Lisp implementation:

```lisp
#lang racket

(define (nearest_age arr age closest)
  (cond
    ((null? arr) closest)
    ((< (abs (- age (car arr))) (abs (- age closest)))
      (nearest_age (cdr arr) age (car arr)))
    (else (nearest_age (cdr arr) age closest))))

(nearest_age '(23 78 51 29 36 90 12 30 79) 50 10000)
```

In each iteration, this:

1. Checks if the list is empty. If it is: return the `closest` value.
2. If the absolute difference between the current closest is greater than the absolute difference between the first element of the list: recur over the rest of the list but replace `closest` with the current first element.
3. Otherwise: recur over the rest of the list, keeping current values of `age` and `closest`.

Here's a trace of the computation:

```
>(nearest_age '(23 78 51 29 36 90 12 30 79) 50 10000)
>(nearest_age '(78 51 29 36 90 12 30 79) 50 23)
>(nearest_age '(51 29 36 90 12 30 79) 50 23)
>(nearest_age '(29 36 90 12 30 79) 50 51)
>(nearest_age '(36 90 12 30 79) 50 51)
>(nearest_age '(90 12 30 79) 50 51)
>(nearest_age '(12 30 79) 50 51)
>(nearest_age '(30 79) 50 51)
>(nearest_age '(79) 50 51)
>(nearest_age '() 50 51)
<51
51
```

---

### Binary Search Version

If you do want a version that implements binary search, refer to the other answer and the comments (I also wrote up a similar algorithm with a Python solution if you want to read it here: https://gist.github.com/hayesall/bde9ff0f90c99af175db9d41d53881d4).

If you want to apply it to your array, you should be able to sort it first with `sorted(arr)`.